# Android Pass in generic object as a parameter

Tags: java, android, generics

I have a menu class which duplicates a method four times where the only difference is I pass in a different parameter, see code below:

```
public abstract class MenuActivity extends SherlockActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    ActionBar ab = getSherlock().getActionBar();
    SherlockHelper.setupActionBar(ab, this);
}

// If the menu creation is updated, please make
// sure the same changes are made in the SavedResultsActivity.
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return createMenu(this, menu);
}

public static Intent InstructionsIntent(Object aActivity){
    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    return i;
}

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockActivity aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = ((SherlockActivity) aActivity).getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent((Context) aActivity, SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
}   

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockListActivity aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = aActivity.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
} 

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockFragmentActivity aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = aActivity.getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity, InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity, SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
} 

public static boolean createMenu(SherlockFragment aActivity, Menu menu){

    MenuInflater inflater = aActivity.getSherlockActivity().getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

    Intent i = new Intent((Context) aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), InstructionsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("Flag", "firstInstructions");

    menu.findItem(R.id.hearing_test).setIntent(i);
    menu.findItem(R.id.learn).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), LearnActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), ShareActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.locate).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), MapActivity.class));
    menu.findItem(R.id.saved).setIntent(new Intent(aActivity.getSherlockActivity(), SavedResultsActivity.class));
    return true;
}
```

}

I want to change it so I only have one method that passes in a generic object as a parameter but I can't figure out how to do this! I've tried passing in an object such as the `InstructionsIntent` method (which doesn't work so I've had to duplicate the intent in each method), but it crashes every time unless I split it out like I have done. Can anyone point me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: I really think it should work, when you just make that `public static boolean createMenu(Activity aActivity, Menu menu)` and in `onCreateOptionsMenu` you set up a detour for fragments in that you pass the value of "getActivity()" in case of `this` is a fragment.

Comment: So what do you mean by that then, could you give me an example please?

Comment: All your Activities extend `Activity` right? So they have a "is-a" relation wih Activity. That means you can pass them to a method that requires a parameter of type `Activity`. `Fragment` is a different story. If I have more time later, I will write a complete answer.

Comment: I can't have an Activity as a parameter, if the activity I need to use it on extends ListActivity, so I have to seperate the methods out for every different extension I use for my different activites